# How to set contentInset of a ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, swiftui

I can't seem to find how to set the contentInset of a ScrollView. My goal is to make the last object in my ScrollView above the Purple Main Button.

[image]

If there is a command, could someone help how to implement this into my current code below. I would appreciate your help!

```
struct Overview: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(0..<5) {
                        Text("Item \($0)")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .frame(width: 340, height: 200)
                            .background(Color("Boxes"))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("Overview", displayMode: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could put an invisible view underneath your `ScrollView` content and give it bottom padding.

For example with `Color.clear` and a bottom-padding of 300.

```
struct Overview: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(0..<5) {
                        Text("Item \($0)")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .frame(width: 340, height: 200)
                            .background(Color("Boxes"))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }

                    Color.clear.padding(.bottom, 300)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("Overview", displayMode: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Spacer(minLength: 300) would be better in my opinion than an empty color

Comment: Whilst this works, the scroll bars doesn't adjust themselves as they would with an inset.

Comment: This is a hack... not really a solution

Answer (score 52):

Just add a `padding` to the `VStack` embedded inside the `ScrollView`.

Using paddings with the embedded stacks provides the same behaviour as content insets.

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        // Some content //
    }
    .padding(.bottom, 200)    // Choose a value that works for you
}
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer instead

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the content will not scroll behind what you have on the bottom if you are using blur's and visualEffectView's.  So you will lose that nice effect that you see in the messages app when you scroll down below the text input area.  Really no idea how to achieve that and maintain your scroll indicators.

Comment: alionthego if you use a `ZStack` leaving the `visualEffectView`'s on top of the `ScrollView` there should not be a problem with this approach.

Comment: Jorge Fries, there is indeed a problem with the scroll indicator.

Answer (score 26):

iOS 15's SwiftUI now has a [safeAreaInset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview/safeareainset(edge:alignment:spacing:content:)-6j9t7) modifier.
It's also correctly adjusts scroll bars.

```swift
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
    // scrollview's content
}
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
    // some bottom-sticked content, or just –
    Spacer()
        .frame(height: 44)
}
```

Comment: Same problem as mentioned above with this solution; the scroll indicator is not following correctly :/

Comment: I think the position of indicator is correct in this way. ScrollView can adjust its indicator automatically.

Comment: This works for me, it adjusts the scroll indicators as well. Testing on iOS 16.4

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15 I just add negative padding to the VStack.

```
struct Overview: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(0..<5) {
                        Text("Item \($0)")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .frame(width: 340, height: 200)
                            .background(Color("Boxes"))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, -50)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("Overview", displayMode: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, a negative padding does not achieve the same effect as a content inset.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/safe-area-insets-2/) has a pretty good solution that seems to work on iOS13+ and calculates the correct inset automatically so you don't need to guess. It looks like it also doesn't handle the scroll indicator though.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add some Stack

```
struct Overview: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    VStack {}.frame(width: 16, height: 40)
                    ForEach(0..<5) {
                        Text("Item \($0)")
                    }
                    VStack {}.frame(width: 16, height: 40)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("Overview", displayMode: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```